# Tinymce editor selector

Tags: javascript, editor, target

hey guys I have tinymce editor

> tinymce.init ({
>    selector: "textarea", 
>   });

I want to have some textareas without tinymce editor tools and some with that selector , how can I make that exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

You Can simply add and ID with your textarea on which you want tinymce then update your selector for init function. i.e

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea#editable'
});
```

Check more options here:

> https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#replaceatextareaelementwithideditable

Comment: I have problem with selector prop : Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2322)

Example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-engelbart-3okdl?file=/src/App.tsx